# Rebuild Customer grid index not working - Getting Error

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.3, magento2.2.2

anyone can help me about this issues, i'm getting this error. I'm trying to fix it, But i could not found any solution.

> {"0":"Notice: Undefined index: PK_CUSTOMER_ENTITY in
>   /vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/AbstractEntity.php on
>   line 769"

and Please check below screenshot.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to run the reindex on the server directly ?

Comment: Yes many times, but still this error is coming again and again

Comment: Did you create any customer attribute / created by any extension?

Comment: Yes, i was create many attributes. But same files and database working fine on localhost, but on live server issues are occurring ..

Comment: Thanks Guys, I have fix this issue. issues is in this table customer_entity. I was just update this table.